# NestJs : How to implement a Controller using nestjsx/crud and manual implementation together

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Under my **Nestjs** app , i am using **@nestjsx/crud** to handle the crud actions

But for some paths and some cases i need to implement the call for services manually which runs some sql queries.

**My Controller would look like this**

```
import {Controller, Get} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Crud, CrudController } from '@nestjsx/crud';
import { TodoEntity } from './todo.entity';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';

@Crud({
  model: {
    type: TodoEntity
  }
})

@Controller('todo')
export class TodoController implements CrudController<TodoEntity> {
  constructor(public todoService: TodoService) {}

  // I WANT TO DO THIS in addition to the previous tremanet->
  @Get('/mypath')
  public async myManulaTreatment() {
    return await this.todoService.getManual();
  }
}
```

**My service  would look like this :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmCrudService } from "@nestjsx/crud-typeorm";
import { TodoEntity } from './todo.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {getManager , getConnection} from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class TodoService extends TypeOrmCrudService<TodoEntity>{
  constructor(@InjectRepository(TodoEntity) repo) {
    super(repo)
  }

  // THIS IS MY MANUAL TREATMENT
  async getManual(){
    const entityManager = await getConnection().manager.query("SELECT * FROM "+process.env.DATABASE_DB.mytable);
  }
}
```

But i got this error :

```
Class 'TodoController' incorrectly implements interface 'CrudController<TodoEntity>'.
  Property 'service' is missing in type 'TodoController' but required in type 'CrudController<TodoEntity>'.
```

Suggestions ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to `override` the routes:  https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#routes-override

Then you can inject services in constructor and use it in routes.

Example:

```
import {
  Crud,
  CrudController,
  Override,
  CrudRequest,
  ParsedRequest,
  ParsedBody,
  CreateManyDto,
} from '@nestjsx/crud';

@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Hero,
  }
})
@Controller('heroes')
export class HeroesCrud implements CrudController<Hero> {
  constructor(public service: HeroesService) {}

  get base(): CrudController<Hero> {
    return this;
  }

  @Override()
  getMany(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
  ) {
    return this.base.getManyBase(req);
  }

  @Override('getOneBase')
  getOneAndDoStuff(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
  ) {
    return this.base.getOneBase(req);
  }

  @Override()
  createOne(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    @ParsedBody() dto: Hero,
  ) {
    return this.base.createOneBase(req, dto);
  }

  @Override()
  createMany(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    @ParsedBody() dto: CreateManyDto<Hero>
  ) {
    return this.base.createManyBase(req, dto);
  }

  @Override('updateOneBase')
  coolFunction(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    @ParsedBody() dto: Hero,
  ) {
    return this.base.updateOneBase(req, dto);
  }

  @Override('replaceOneBase')
  awesomePUT(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    @ParsedBody() dto: Hero,
  ) {
    return this.base.replaceOneBase(req, dto);
  }

  @Override()
  async deleteOne(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
  ) {
    return this.base.deleteOneBase(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not what he needs to do. He wants to keep the existing functionality AND add a new endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling your `TodoService` todoService, you should just call it `service` and make sure to pass it to `super(service)` to make sure the base class has its proper dependencies too. [Here's the docs for adding-routes from nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#adding-routes)